# Proper Use of YouTube API

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Would I need to create links to YouTube's Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy when I use the YouTube's API on my website? I was looking around for requirements but didn't see anything that mandated creating a Privacy Policy and Terms and Conditions that linked back to YouTube's Terms and Conditions. I've used the YouTube API to create a YouTube search engine on my website and want to make sure I'm in compliance with YouTube's policies.

Answer (score 0):

The terms and conditions and privacy poilicy are for **you** in a capacity of consuming the service.

It's your responsiblity is to read the documentation and ensure you code adheres by the policies. You dont need to re-publish this on your website.

The only time you will need to present a end user any kind of terms and conditions if end users are publishing content on YouTube as identified in clause 9.1

> 9.1 Required Notice. If your API Client(s) uses any YouTube API Services to permit users to upload videos to YouTube websites,
>   applications, services or products, the screen or window in which the
>   end user clicks the "upload" button must display the following warning
>   in the language(s) available on your API Client(s):

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.